# PageViewer Vertical Scrolling

Tags: android, view, pageviews

I have a `pageViewer` which has a gridview in it. But i dont find the `PagerViewer.SetOnScrollListner` for vertical Scroll..Can anyone help me rgarding this..Previously i was doing `m_oGridView.SetOnScrollListner`. Below is my pageViewer

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

I am getting the gridView inside PageViewer but i need a callback function which gets called when gridview is scrolled in the activity